# How to know when i'm waiting in a poll system call?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, embedded

We're accessing an FPGA device via the Linux UIO device infrastructure. Under this model, we receive interrupts from the FPGA by poll(2)ing the device node /dev/uio0.

We'd like to make sure that we don't miss any interrupts. Hence we need a way to notify clients of the class encapsulating the device file descriptor when our polling thread is ready waiting in the poll(2) system call, so that we can be sure that we're only telling the FPGA to start generating interrupts when we're actually waiting for them.

Do you know of any way to achieve that?

Thanks,
Damian

Comment: Can you enable interrupts when the device node is opened and disable it again when it is closed?

Comment: @tangrs I think I could, but I don't see how that would help with polling, after the file's been opened already...

Comment: Well, in your driver that handles the `/dev/uio0` device, design it in a way that it enables the interrupts for that device when the device node is opened by a userspace program.

Comment: It kind of sounds like the chosen approach overall may not be the best.  Could you be more specific about the fear?  Are these one-shot events, or repeating that you hope to catch with a subsequent poll() without stopping and restarting the source of events?   At an extreme you could add another advisory node where a read() would block until a poll() of the node of interest began, and use its unblocking another thread to send your notification, but resorting to that kind of thing casts suspicion on the overall approach chosen.

Comment: I agree. This approach to the problem seems to be going against how the Linux kernel works. What are the specifics of what you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: @ChrisStratton We have both single-shot and repeating events (we actually have different independent blocks on our FPGA, each with its own UIO device). I didn't get what you meant with advisory node. The only interface we have to the FPGA is *one* file descriptor that we mmap to access the FPGA's registers and "read" to receive interrupts.